# MTP - Samsung Galaxy S7 + Debian Bullseye

Tags: linux, debian, android, mtp

I have device and OS like in subject.

I **have** turned on Developer mode, USB debugging and MTP mode for USB.

What I get:

```
% mtp-detect 
libmtp version: 1.1.17

Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Samsung: Galaxy models (MTP) (04e8:6860) @ bus 5, dev 46
Attempting to connect device(s)
error returned by libusb_claim_interface() = -6LIBMTP PANIC: Unable to initialize device
Unable to open raw device 0
OK.
```

I have searched around the web, but no solution I found seems to work. I do allow USB connection from the computer every time.